# When calling onItemLongClickListener,onItemClickListener also works

Tags: android, android-listview, onitemclicklistener, onitemlongclicklistener

I have `ListView` in which `onItemClickListener` and `onLongItemClickListener` are used for different options. It works fine in `jellybean`. But in `Nexus5` when I long click on the `ListView`, both `onItemClickListener` and `onLongItemClickListener` are called. Why is this happening? Does anyone know about it?

Comment: what do you return from onItemLongClick?

Comment: onLongItemClick will navigate to another page

Comment: what do you return from onItemLongClick?

Comment: return false, is there any problem with that?

Comment: Could you please explain what happens when returns true and false

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should set the return value of the `OnItemLongClickListener` to **true**

```
private AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener itemLongClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //... Do stuff
        return true;
    }
};
```

This is how the event tells its parent that the click event has been handled. If it is set to false the `OnItemClickListener` will also be fired, invoking its listener method as well.

Comment: @nail, which means if we return false the parent doesn't understand that longclick is done. so it will call the onitemclick. Am i right?

Comment: Yes. If you return false, you tell the AdapterView that you want the OnItemClick to also fire which in turn will invoke its listener

Comment: Pleasure. Go have a look at this if you have more questions :) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html